# How to install GD Library? Laravel at AWS Lambda with Bref

Tags: php, laravel, lambda, serverless, bref

When using Intervention\Image in laravel on lambda
The following error has occurred.
By the way, it works in the local environment.

I have to add gd.

> [2021-08-17 10:37:18] DEV.ERROR: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
> {"exception":"[object] (Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException(code: 0):
> GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
> at /var/task/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Driver.php:19)

What I looked up

> https://bref.sh/docs/environment/php.html#extensions

> https://github.com/brefphp/extra-php-extensions

Deployment method

We are deploying to lambda using the sls command.

> sls deploy --stage dev

Based on the investigation, the following is implemented

> composer require bref/extra-php-extensions

Added below
serverless.yml

```
plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref
    - ./vendor/bref/extra-php-extensions #add

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        image:
            name: laravel
        events:
            -   httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80}
            - ${bref:layer.console}
            - ${bref-extra:gd-php-80} #add
```

Even if the above settings are added and deployed, they are not updated. .. why?

enviroment

- Laravel Framework 8.33.1
- PHP 7.4.3
- bref
- serverless

I'm sorry if English is strange.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://bref.sh/docs/environment/php.html#customizing-phpini-in-extra-layers) it seems you still need to register the extension in a custom *.ini file. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Before that, the way to write serverless.yml was strange.
I'll fix that.
However, an error has occurred.
What should I do in this case?

`An error occurred: WebLambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message: "Please don't provide Handler or Runtime or Layer when the intended function PackageType is Image.`

edit
`serverless.yml edit. add functions->web add layers`

Comment: @nitrin0 I am also facing the same issue. I've added the changes in serverless.yml file after installing the required package using composer. Then I created a custom ini file. Now it is showing only {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: @Muhammed Shihabudeen Labba A
I know the cause.
[aws blog in japanese](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/news/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/)
↑
Layers cannot be added to the container image. So you need to add a layer to the container image itself and include it in the image.
But I don't know how to include it in the container image. I would add it by writing it in the Dockerfile ...
Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: @Muhammed
How about this?Dockerfile edit.
FROM bref/php-80-fpm
COPY . /var/task
COPY --from=bref/extra-gd-php-80 /opt /opt
CMD [ "public/index.php" ]

Comment: @ニホニウム I just followed the bref document to install extra php extensions and later I have checked whether it is installed or not using the command 
echo "GD: ", extension_loaded('gd') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';

Comment: @Muhammed I can't answer because I don't know what you're doing right now.
So, which site can you see only in Japanese?
Especially in the comments section　https://teratail.com/questions/362103

Answer (score 0):

Put the layers into web "tag".

```
plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref
    - ./vendor/bref/extra-php-extensions #add

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        image:
            name: laravel
        layers:
            - ${bref-extra:gd-php-80} #add
        events:
            -   httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80}
            - ${bref:layer.console}
```

Then add the folder php/conf.d inside put a file with extension .ini. For example php.ini. In it just put:

```
extension=gd
```